# Using Coalesce with Multiple Joins

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a report view in SQL Server. I need to select data from two columns in a table. Each column has FK to two separate tables. There can only be one value between the two columns; either a FK identifier to the respective table or a null value. As a person cannot have both roles.

**dbo.Personnel**:

```
Name |  InternalRoleID | ExternalRoleID
-----+-----------------+----------------
John |       3         |      Null
Bob  |       Null      |      3
Rick |       5         |      Null
Anna |       6         |      Null
```

**dbo.InternalRoles**:

```
ID | Name
---+------------------------------
3  |  Accountant
3  |  Manager
5  |  Supervisor
6  |  Worker
```

**dbo.ExternalRoles**:

```
ID | Name
---+------------------------------
3  |  Delivery Driver
3  |  Cleaner
5  |  Electrician
6  |  Auditor
```

Can anyone assist with the best query to use. I have tried coalesce, but i am not sure if that is the most efficient way.

It is part of another series of queries, would display As [RoleName]:

```
Name | RoleName      | Location | TimeonSite
-----+---------------+----------+------------
John | Accountant    |    A     |    Null
Bob  | Manager       |    B     |     4
Rick | Electrician   |    C     |     2
Anna | Supervisor    |    C     |    33
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the desired output.

Comment: It will be nice to have the desired output that you want.

Comment: you have two records with same Id 3 in both Internal and External Roles tables. Which one should be selected and why?

Comment: Based on your input and expected output, how is Rick defined as 'Electrician'? Shouldn't it be 'Supervisor'? (Internal Id 5). Suggest you review your question.

Comment: Yes, sorry, the roles in the example output are not reflective of the numbering above. just demonstration

Comment: As the others have said, you should [edit] your question to reflect this. That way, we have a [mcve] of your issue, and are better able to accurately answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

Try below query. It will result in multiple record for same name 'John' and 'Bob' as you have multiple Internal and external roles for same Id (Id 3). If that's not what you want, let me know which one you expect to be displayed.

```
CREATE TABLE #Personnel
    (
        Name VARCHAR(100) ,
        InternalRoleID INT ,
        ExternalRoleID INT
    );

CREATE TABLE #InternalRoles
    (
        ID INT ,
        Name VARCHAR(100)
    );

CREATE TABLE #ExternalRoles
    (
        ID INT ,
        NAme VARCHAR(100)
    );

INSERT INTO #Personnel
VALUES ( 'John', 3, NULL ) ,
       ( 'Bob', NULL, 3 ) ,
       ( 'Rick', 5, NULL ) ,
       ( 'Anna', 6, NULL );


INSERT INTO #InternalRoles ( ID ,
                             Name )
VALUES ( 3, 'Accountant' ) ,
       ( 3, 'Manager' ) ,
       ( 5, 'Supervisor' ) ,
       ( 6, 'Worker' );



INSERT INTO #ExternalRoles ( ID ,
                             NAme )
VALUES ( 3, 'Delivery Driver' ) ,
       ( 3, 'Cleaner' ) ,
       ( 5, 'Electrician' ) ,
       ( 6, 'Auditor' );


SELECT P.Name ,
       COALESCE(IR.Name, ER.NAme) AS RoleName
FROM   #Personnel P
       LEFT JOIN #InternalRoles IR ON P.InternalRoleID = IR.ID
       LEFT JOIN #ExternalRoles ER ON P.ExternalRoleID = ER.ID;

DROP TABLE #ExternalRoles;
DROP TABLE #Personnel;
DROP TABLE #InternalRoles;
```

Comment: No worries. You may still wanna update your sample data and mark answer as accepted so that it help some one else in the future.

Answer (score 2):

There's a few ways you can handle this:

- Use `COALESCE` to return the first non-`NULL` value ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ea305/7/0))

  ```
  SELECT Personnel.Name, COALESCE(InternalRoles.Name, ExternalRoles.Name, 'Unknown') AS RoleName
  FROM Personnel
  LEFT OUTER JOIN InternalRoles ON InternalRoles.ID = Personnel.InternalRoleID AND Personnel.ExternalRoleID IS NULL
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ExternalRoles ON ExternalRoles.ID = Personnel.ExternalRoleID AND Personnel.InternalRoleID IS NULL
  ```
- Use `ISNULL` to return a second value if a given value is `NULL` ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ea305/8/0))

  ```
  SELECT Personnel.Name, ISNULL(InternalRoles.Name, ExternalRoles.Name) AS RoleName
  FROM Personnel
  LEFT OUTER JOIN InternalRoles ON InternalRoles.ID = Personnel.InternalRoleID AND Personnel.ExternalRoleID IS NULL
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ExternalRoles ON ExternalRoles.ID = Personnel.ExternalRoleID AND Personnel.InternalRoleID IS NULL
  ```
- Use a `CASE` statement to define if-then-else behavior ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ea305/9/0))

  ```
  SELECT Personnel.Name, CASE WHEN Personnel.InternalRoleID IS NOT NULL THEN InternalRoles.Name ELSE ExternalRoles.Name END AS RoleName
  FROM Personnel
  LEFT OUTER JOIN InternalRoles ON InternalRoles.ID = Personnel.InternalRoleID AND Personnel.ExternalRoleID IS NULL
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ExternalRoles ON ExternalRoles.ID = Personnel.ExternalRoleID AND Personnel.InternalRoleID IS NULL
  ```

Realistically, the only consideration you'll need to make is what best suits the style of your query, as all of these have the same execution plans and relatively the same execution time. Personally, I'd recommend using `COALESCE`, as it allows you to display a default value if one of the Name values in your Internal/ExternalRoles tables happens to be `NULL`, if you wish to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can try this:

```
select [Name],
       coalesce((select [Name] from InternalRoles where id = p.InternalRoleId),
                (select [Name] from ExternalRoles where id = p.ExternalRoleId)) [RoleNamE]
from Personnel p
```

Comment: This causes an error when using the data sample with non-unique IDs in OP's question, as it's returning multiple values (See this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ea305/10)).

Comment: @Hoppeduppeanut As you correctly mentioned, those are IDs and IDs are unique by default... That's why I proposed such query. But in general, if those columns weren't unique, it would generate errors - you are correct on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :- Using Case

```
SELECT p.Name, CASE WHEN isnull(i.Name,'') = '' THEN e.Name ELSE i.Name END 
  FROM Personnel p LEFT JOIN InternalRoles i ON p.InternalRoleID = i.ID 
               LEFT JOIN ExternalRoles e ON p.ExternalRoleID = e.ID
```